# HTML / PHP Email Form: Submit button doesn't respond

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm working on a quote submission form for my company, and running into an issue with the form functionality (namely, the Submit button does nothing). Currently, the form is below:

```
<form action="quotethanks.php" form id="contact-form">
<fieldset>
  <p>
    <label class="name">
      <input type="text" name="first" value="First Name:*">
      <span class="errors"><span class="error">*This is not a valid name.</span> <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span></span></label>

    <label class="name">
      <input type="text" name="last" value="Last Name:*">
      <span class="errors"><span class="error">*This is not a valid name.</span> <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span></span></label>

    <label class="name">
      <input type="text" name="business" value="Business Name:*">
      <span class="errors"><span class="error">*This is not a valid name.</span> <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span></span></label>

    <label class="email">
      <input type="text" name="email" value="E-mail Address:*">
      <span class="errors"><span class="error">*This is not a valid email.</span> <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span></span></label>

    <label class="phone">
      <input type="text" name="phone" value="Phone Number:*">
      <span class="errors"><span class="error">*This is not a valid phone number.</span> <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span></span></label>

 <label class="message">   Type of quote: * 
  <select name="type">
    <option value="Display Case">Display Case</option>
    <option value="Case Part"> Case Part</option>
    <option value="Service"> Service</option>
    <option value="Other"> Other</option>
  </select></label>

  <br><br>If "other," please define:
  <textarea name="define" id="define"></textarea>
  <br><Br>

  <label class="name">
    <input type="text" name="model" value="Equipment Model Number (if known)">
  </label>

  <label class="name">
    <input type="text" name="serial" value="Equipment Serial Number (if known)">
  </label>

    Quote Description:
  <textarea name="description" id="description"></textarea>
  <br><br>

  <label class="name">
    <input type="text" name="offer" value="Offer Code (if applicable)">
  </label>  
                <div class="clear"></div>
                              <div class="btns">
                                <a class="button" data-type="submit">Submit</a>
                                <a class="button" data-type="reset">Clear</a>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
              </p>
  </p>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

This should then send the entered data to quote_mailer.php, and then redirect to quotethanks.php (the last line of code):

```
<?php 

/*Subject and email variables */ 

$emailSubject = 'Quote Request Submitted'; 
$webMaster = 'lmiller@rsiclimate.com'; 

/* Gathering Data Variables */ 
$firstField = $_POST['first']; 
$lastField = $_POST['last']; 
$businessField = $_POST['business']; 
$emailField = $_POST['email']; 
$phoneField = $_POST['phone']; 
$typeField = $_POST['type']; 
$defineField = $_POST['define']; 
$modelField = $_POST['model']; 
$serialField = $_POST['serial']; 
$descriptionField = $_POST['description']; 
$offerField = $_POST['offer']; 

$body = "<br><hr><br>"; 
$body.= "Name: ".$firstField." ".$lastField." <br>"; 
$body.= "Business Name: ".$businessField." <br>"; 
$body.= "Email: ".$emailField." <br>"; 
$body.= "Phone Number: ".$phoneField." <br>"; 
$body.= "Quote Type: ".$typeField." <br>"; 
$body.= "If other, define: ".$defineField." <br>";
$body.= "Model Number, if known: ".$modelField." <br>";  
$body.= "Serial Number, if known: ".$serialField." <br>"; 
$body.= "Quote Description: ".$descriptionField." <br>"; 
$body.= "Offer Code: ".$offerField." <br>"; 

$headers = "From: ".$emailField."\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n"; 
if(mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers)) 
header('Location: contact-form-thank-you.html'); 
?>
```

The issue I'm running into is on the form's actual page, all data gets entered, and then the Submit button does nothing. It shows up, you can click it, but for all visible purposes nothing happens. While I've worked with HTML more than a little, creating PHP-driven forms is relatively new to me so I'm not really seeing where in this code an issue might be.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try <input type="submit" value="Submit"> instead of <a class="button" data-type="submit">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an input submit and not an anchor, so change this

```
<a class="button" data-type="submit">Submit</a>
```

To

```
<input class="button" type="submit" name="submit">Submit</a>
```

In your php code add instead a checking for `isset()` of the button

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $emailSubject = 'Quote Request Submitted'; 
    $webMaster = 'lmiller@rsiclimate.com'; 
   //all your code here
} else {
   //print the form
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I made those changes, and the form is still looking to be inactive upon clicking submit. Oddly, if I leave the required fields blank the errors appear as if the button is working. It seems to have a problem after that check for errors...

Comment: Add method to the form `<form action="quotethanks.php" form id="contact-form" method="post">`

Comment: I got that added in, still unresponsive

Comment: My best clue is to simplify the form to only 1 input and let it work, the move to add other, i can't see any other errors right now

Comment: A systematic error check would make sense. I have a feeling it breaks down somewhere in the handling of the error messages, since those will pop up but no actual form handling occurs. This whole site was built by another designer, so a lot of the background is lost to me (praying for approval to revamp to Wordpress)

Comment: Yeah that might cause the issue.

Comment: Well thank you for your assistance! Never used this service before, impressed with the folks out there willing to help out!